# an easy way to serialise c# objects

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using Newtonsoft.Json to turn json into objects, that works fine. I was wondering if there's a nice way to reverse the process noting that i dont want to jsonise all the object fields. To paraphrase, is there a way to use Newtonsoft.Json to produce thinned down jsonised object representations?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easiest way to serialize and store objects in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719498/easiest-way-to-serialize-and-store-objects-in-c)

Comment: not really, the responses mostly say things like 'json is friendly', my question is a whole lot more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the [`JsonIgnore`](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/ReducingSerializedJSONSize.html) to opt-out properties that you don't want to be included in the JSON serialization?  See this topic:

http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/ReducingSerializedJSONSize.html